# Let C be the circle $|z|=1$. Evaluate $\int_{c}\frac{e^{2\pi z}}{(2z+1)^3}dz.$

Tags: contour-integration

> Let C be the circle $|z|=1$. Evaluate $$\int_{c}\frac{e^{2\pi z}}{(2z+1)^3}dz.$$

Any idea, suggestion, advice or solution.

Comment: How about residue theorem?

Comment: can you possible to show me how to do it ?

Comment: It seems [your class mate (?) was here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1843790/97236) before you.

Comment: @mickep Thank you!! I thought I was going nuts as I remembered this question and even having answered it, but I couldn't find it. Now I understand: it was erased by the poster.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)

$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$

with the appropiate assumptions and choices.

By the way, the result is $\;\cfrac{\pi^3i}{2e^{\pi}}\;$

Comment: You  mean $f^{(n)}(a)$ on the LHS?

Comment: @Batominovski Thank you, yes: of course. Edited.

Comment: @Joanpemo are u willing to show me the solution because i'm confusing there are different answer from Slup and you. which one is correct?

Comment: @Runa Check it. I already did and my answer agrees with Wolfram's, but perhaps it still is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

apply 
$$I=i 2 \pi [Res_{z=\frac{-1}{2}}f(z)]$$

Comment: Should be  a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

I am assuming that $C$ is oriented counterclockwise. Clearly:
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{2\pi z}}{(2z+1)^3}$$
is holomorphic on:
$$\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|<1\}\setminus \{-\frac{1}{2}\}$$
Using the above theorem we obtain:
$$\int_C\frac{e^{2\pi z}}{(2z+1)^3}dz=2\pi i\, \mathrm{res}_{z_0=-\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{e^{2\pi z}}{(2z+1)^3})$$
Now we compute:
$$\mathrm{res}_{z_0=\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{e^{2\pi z}}{(2z+1)^3})=\frac{1}{2!}\lim_{z\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}[(\frac{e^{2\pi z}}{(2z+1)^3})(z+\frac{1}{2})^3]^{(2)}=\frac{1}{2!\cdot 8}\lim_{z\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}(e^{2\pi z})^{(2)}=\frac{1}{2!\cdot 8}\lim_{z\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}(2\pi)^2e^{2\pi z}=\frac{1}{2!\cdot 8}(2\pi)^2e^{-\pi}=\frac{\pi^2}{4e^{\pi}}$$